# Constraining tank_auth views to a div on a web age

Tags: codeigniter, web-applications, tankauth

Hi Tank_auth & web Gurus!

I have tank_auth working with my CodeIgniter application. Currently, the login/register views of tank_auth take over the entire screen. On my website, I would like the login/register views to occupy a div that I define. For example, I want the login/pw fields to just appear in the top right corner and not take over the whole screen...Can you point me in the right direction? - I read somewhere that I'd have to somehow constrain the view in a div but for the life of me I did not understand how!

Much obliged,

Mmiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create div for the login. Create a view for the login. Populate the div with a javascript call to the view.

```
<?php

//controller
//users.php
class Users {

//...

    public function div_login()
    {
        $this->load->view('div_login_view.php');
    }

//...

//------------------------------------------

//view
//div_login_view.php
echo form_open('users/login');
echo form_input('username');
echo form_password('password');
echo form_submit('Login');
echo form_close();

//------------------------------------------


//index page (or whatever page you want the form on)



<div id="login_div"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var login_form = $.get('/users/div_login');
        if (login_form.status === 200){
            $('#login_div').html(login_form.responseText)
        }else{
            alert('There was an error getting the login form.');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick and also helped me understand how to integrated tank_auth into my webstite. Much obliged!

Comment: Hi stormdrain, I'm new to CI, so not greatly familiar with how it works, but I'm wanting to do the exact same thing. Is doing it through Javascript really the only way? Why can you not do something like (pseudo code here): if( !$this->tankauth->is_logged_in() ) $this->load->view('/auth/login/'); ? I simply want to load the login form (or logout) embedded in a current site. Is that possible?

Comment: Well this guy wanted to do it in a div on top of the current page. You can do it as you say no problem, but it will be the whole page -- not in a container. If you want it dynamic (say like a login form popping up on your home page), js will be the only option. Play around a bit, and ask a question if you have one :)